# How to Find fine differences between two Objects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, reflection

How can I find value differences between two objects of same type. For-example I have a Rectangle class having x, y, width, height properties and two objects of rectangle class. How can I find(either programmatically or any visualization tool or library etc) which properties of one rectangle differ from second rectangle?

Or is there any way of getting object state on console or to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are just fine if you actually *know* the class of your objects at *compile time*. If not this is the case you are still lucky because Objective C allows you to explore the instance variables of your object at runtime. A pseudo-code of comparing two unknown object could be:

```
+ (BOOL) compareObject:(id)obj1 withObject:(id)obj2 {

  unsigned int varCount1, varCount2;
  if ([obj1 class] != [obj2 class]) return NO;

  Ivar *vars1 = class_copyIvarList([obj1 class], &varCount1);
  Ivar *vars2 = class_copyIvarList([obj2 class], &varCount2);
  BOOL match = YES;

  for (int i = 0; i < varCount1; i++) {
    Ivar var1 = vars1[i];

    for (int j = 0; i < varCount2; j++) {
      Ivar var2 = vars2[j];
        if (strcmp(ivar_getName(var1), ivar_getName(var2)) == 0) {
          if (object_getIvar(obj1, var1) != object_getIvar(obj2, var2)) {
            match = NO;
            break;
          }
        } 
    }

    if (!match) break;

  }

  free(vars1);
  free(vars2);

  return match;
}
```

Comment: This is going to find objects different that are really the same, such as: `NSStrings` with the same content but different classes (since `NSString` is actually a class cluster, not a class), and objects that use ivars for metadata rather than identity/content. That might be fine for your case, of course. :)

Comment: My intention was more to show the asker that there is a tool to explore the instance variables in objective c, for this reason I wrote "pseudo-code". How he will use it, how to filter and refine the results is more up to his specific case.

Answer (score 0):

If you print the description of the object, you will get to know about the values.

For eg.,

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10,10,20,20);
Rectangle *rectObject = [[Rectangle alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
NSLog(@"Desc : %@",[rectObject description]);
```

Also, if you want to compare,

you can get x origin by  `NSLog(@"Origin x: %f", rectObject.frame.origin.x);`

you can get y origin by  `NSLog(@"Origin y: %f", rectObject.frame.origin.y);`

Similarly you can get the width by,

```
NSLog(@"Width : %f", rectObject.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"Height : %f", rectObject.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

if x,y etc are float then assume Rect1 and Rect2 are two objects then

```
NSLog(@"for Rect1 \nx %f y %f \nFor Rect2 \nx %f y%f",Rect1.x,Rect1.y,Rect2.x,Rext2.y);
```

this will show the x and y of Rect1 and Rect2 respectively

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check, if two variables point to the *same instance*, you can compare them using `obj1 == obj2`.

If you want to check, if two different instances of your class do have the same member values, you have to check each value on its own. (eg. `obj1.property1 == obj2.property2`).

If you just want to check the same, while debugging, just put in a breakpoint and have a look in the debug area of xcode. You can inspect all living objects there. Just press the arrow right next to your object. Local variables (existing at the time of the breakpoin) are listed directly, members are folded into self.